# Can't convert from model to viewmodel, using AutoMapper asp.net core

Tags: asp.net

I am using Auto mapper to map between modelviews and models. I have followed the same steps given by the Auto mapper documentation and still can't find where the issue is.

```
   public class RegisterStaffViewModel
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "StaffName Required")]
    public string StaffName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender Required")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "StaffCode Required")]
    public string StaffCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Department")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Department is Required")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string CardNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobileno Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Wrong Mobileno")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EmailID Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Position")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Position is Required")]
    public int? PositionId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Staff Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Staff Type is Required")]
    public int? StaffTypeId { get; set; }
    public string CardIdNo { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsUpdated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser DeletedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Departments Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Positions Position { get; set; }
    public virtual StaffTypes StaffType { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser UpdatedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AttendanceRecorderViewModel> AttendanceRecorder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ManageLeavesViewModel> ManageLeaves { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RegisterDevicesViewModel> RegisterDevices { get; set; }
}
```

=============================================================================================

```
   public partial class RegisterStaffs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StaffName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string StaffCode { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string CardNo { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public int? PositionId { get; set; }
    public int? StaffTypeId { get; set; }
    public string CardIdNo { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsUpdated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser DeletedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Departments Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Positions Position { get; set; }
    public virtual StaffTypes StaffType { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser UpdatedByNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AttendanceRecorder> AttendanceRecorder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ManageLeaves> ManageLeaves { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RegisterDevices> RegisterDevices { get; set; }
}
```

============================================================================================

```
    public interface IMapperConfig
{
    IMapper CreateMapper();
}

public class MapperConfig : IMapperConfig
{
    public IMapper CreateMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
       {
           cfg.CreateMap<RegisterStaffs, RegisterStaffViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<AttendanceRecorder, AttendanceRecorderViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<ManageLeaves, ManageLeavesViewModel>();
           cfg.CreateMap<RegisterDevices, RegisterDevicesViewModel>();

       });

        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

==========================================================================================

```
 public async Task<ReturnResult<List<RegisterStaffViewModel>>> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        var result = new ReturnResult<List<RegisterStaff>>();

        try
        {
            var employees = await context.RegisterStaffs.Where(x => (bool)!x.IsDeleted).OrderByDescending(x => x.EntryDate).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
             
            // **here is the error** 
            result.Success(mapper.Map<List<RegisterStaffs>, List<RegisterStaffViewModel>>(employees));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return result;
    }
```

============================================================================================

```
   public class ReturnResult<T>
{
    public ReturnResult()
    {
        ErrorList = new List<string>();
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public HttpCode HttpCode { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public List<string> ErrorList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set success result with data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Data"></param>
    public void Success(T Data)
    {
        this.IsSuccess = true;
        this.HttpCode = HttpCode.Success;
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set Server Error result with error message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Error"></param>
    public void ServerError(string Error)
    {
        this.IsSuccess = false;
        this.HttpCode = HttpCode.ServerError;
        this.ErrorList.Add(Error);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set Not Found result with error message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Error"></param>
    public void NotFound(string Error)
    {
        this.IsSuccess = false;
        this.HttpCode = HttpCode.NotFound;
        this.ErrorList.Add(Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was here

```
     var result = new ReturnResult<List<RegisterStaff>>();
```

i  have changed it to

```
   var result = new ReturnResult<List<RegisterStaffViewModel>>();
```